# How to validate a field only contains alphanumerics, spaces, dashes & always contains at least one alpha or numeric character?

Tags: c#, validation, server-side-validation

I have an input field that I need to add validation to in c#. The field should only allow alphanumerics, spaces, dashes, and must contain at least one alpha or numeric character. I have the layout of the function, but I am not sure how to formulate the conditions for the if statement.

```
//function call
 ValidateSchoolIDField(request.SchoolID, "School ID", validationErrors);

//function
private static void ValidateSchoolIDField(string value, string fieldname, List<ValidationError> validationErrors)
{
     if (request.SchoolID != alphanumeric/space/dash) 
        validationErrors.Add(new ValidationError("ivalid input for " + fieldName)):
}
```

Comment: look how regex works, there are many examples

Comment: @spzvtbg do you have any link suggestions?

Comment: ^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[\w\d\s-]+$ this regex matches your conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below Regex

Regex.IsMatch(inputString,"[a-zA-Z0-9\s-_]");